# Vlookup in R when operators as strings

Tags: r

I have dataframe that looks like this, it has cutpoint value with operator and WoE value:

```
Cutpoint <- c("<= 0","<= 2","<= 4.5","<= 8","> 8","Missing")
WoE <- c("0.12","0.24","0.45","0.55","0.92","0.99")
dictionary <- data.frame(Cutpoint,WoE)

  Cutpoint  WoE
1     <= 0 0.12
2     <= 2 0.24
3   <= 4.5 0.45
4     <= 8 0.55
5      > 8 0.92
6  Missing 0.99
```

another table looks like this

```
val_A <- c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c","d")
val_B <- c("6","-1","3",NA,"7","8",NA,"9")
table <- data.frame(val_A,val_B)

  val_A val_B
1     a     6
2     a    -1
3     b     3
4     b  <NA>
5     c     7
6     c     8
7     c  <NA>
8     d     9
```

what i'm trying to achieve is to vlookup val_B values in my dictionary so that my result table be like this:

```
  val_A table_B
1     a    0.55
2     a    0.12
3     b    0.45
4     b    0.99
5     c    0.55
6     c    0.55
7     c    0.99
8     d    0.92
```

Thanks a lot for any hint.

Comment: **R** isn't MS Excel. `vlookup` isn't a thing. You want to use a nested `ifelse` statement or `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

This *can* be done, most easily by stripping off the assignment operators and using the information that all but the last 2 cutpoints are "<=".

Set up data:

```
Cutpoint <- c("<= 0","<= 2","<= 4.5","<= 8","> 8","Missing")
WoE <- c("0.12","0.24","0.45","0.55","0.92","0.99")
## stringsAsFactors=FALSE is *essential* here -- or
##  use options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) to set globally
dictionary <- data.frame(Cutpoint,WoE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

val_A <- c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c","d")
val_B <- c("6","-1","3",NA,"7","8",NA,"9")
table <- data.frame(val_A,val_B,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Strip comparison operators and coerce cutpoints to numeric:

```
cuts <- as.numeric(gsub("(<=|>)","",dictionary$Cutpoint))
```

Set up a vector of breakpoints/cutpoints:

```
cuts2 <- c(-Inf,head(cuts,-2),Inf) ## all but last 2 vals of 'cuts', + Inf
```

Find numeric categories:

```
cc <- cut(as.numeric(table$val_B),breaks=cuts2)
```

Substitute the last category for `NA` values:

```
cc2 <- replace(as.numeric(cc),is.na(cc),nrow(dictionary))
```

Now do the lookup:

```
data.frame(val_A,table_B=as.numeric(WoE)[cc2])
```